# How to know which command or compose file has been used to start Docker containers?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

Is there any way to find a source of the docker container script? I have a setup where I can not find any docker-compose.yml file nor the bash script etc that would have run all the Docker containers currently running. I have a virtual machine that starts docker containers on the startup, but have no idea which file is actually run.

Comment: How does the VM "start docker containers on startup"?

Comment: I have no idea, that is why this becomes a bit tricky. The machine was provisioned beforehand, but I have not found any docker-compose file or similar that is being called on startup

Comment: Well *something* must be happening on startup :/  Have you looked in e.g. crontab?

Comment: Yes, crontab is empty. And also /etc/rc.d/ does not seem to contain anything related (it is run on Centos)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the containers are running automatically on reboot and you have no cron/bash profile/rc.local or any other startup screen then that may mean that they are containers with `--restart` option set. You can change that by running below command

```
docker ps -q | xargs docker update --restart no
docker ps -q | xargs docker stop
```

Then restart the machine. The containers should not start. If they do then you have some script somewhere which is starting them

Comment: Thanks Tarun for pointing out this one as well, though I was still unable to find the original script

Comment: It seems you were right Tarun, that the containers were configured to auto restart. The docker-compose file used to create them in the first place is not available at all

Answer (score 3):

i think no option to know which docker-compose file is use.
but you can check manual every you project folder.

the docker-compose mechanism is by matching the `docker-compose.yml file`. so if you run command `sudo docker-compose ps` in every your project folder. docker-compose will match between **the docker-compose file used by container** and **docker-compose file in your project**, if the same than the results will be displayed, if not the results is not displayed